# The method setRequestProperty(String, String) in the type URLConnection is not applicable for the arguments (String, ArrayList<String>)

Tags: android, json, android-imageview, multipartentity, http-request-parameters

I am trying to send multiple images to server but,so I am storing all the images in one arraylist,but after that when I need to send to server,it shows error near line ,,......................

```
 conn.setRequestProperty("image", multimgss);
```

error

```
The method setRequestProperty(String, String) in the type URLConnection is not applicable for the arguments (String, ArrayList<String>)..
```

MainActivity

```
    public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


      String fileName = sourceFileUri;

      /*String[] mimgs = null;
      mimgs.equals(fileName);*/

      ArrayList<String> multimgss=new ArrayList<String>();
      multimgss.add(fileName);

      System.out.println("multipleimagesss"+multimgss);


    try {
        abcd = new JSONArray(multimgss.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
      //abcd=multimgss.add(fileName);


      HttpURLConnection conn = null;
      DataOutputStream dos = null;  
      String lineEnd = "\r\n";
      String twoHyphens = "--";
      String boundary = "*****";
      int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
      byte[] buffer;
      int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
      File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

      if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

           dialog.dismiss(); 

           Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"+imagepath);

           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"+ imagepath);
               }
           }); 

           return 0;

      }
      else
      {
           try { 


               String cats[]=acTextView.getText().toString().split(",");
               JsonParse jp=new JsonParse();
               for(String cat:cats){
                   List<SuggestGetSet> list =jp.getParseJsonWCF(acTextView.getText().toString());
                for(int i = 0;i<list.size();i++){
                  if(list.get(i).getName().equals(cat))
                      catid.add(list.get(i).getId().toString());
                   //params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("parentid",list.get(i).getId()));


                } 
               }



               catsids=catid.toString();
               pname = proname.getText().toString();
                pskucode = proskucode.getText().toString();
                psalerate=prosalerate.getText().toString();
                ppurchaserate=propurchaserate.getText().toString();
                pweight = proweight.getText().toString();
                pweighttype=proweighttype.getText().toString();
            //  pproactives = proactives.getTag().toString();

                 System.out.println("active nu stauts"+catsids);
            //  pdisporder = prodisporder.getText().toString();
                pdesc = prodesc.getText().toString();

                upLoadServerUri = "http://webistname/web-service/addproduct.php?action=addproduct&name="+pname+"&categoryid="+catsids+"&skucode="+pskucode+"&sale_rate="+psalerate+"&purchase_rate="+ppurchaserate+"&weight="+pweight+"&weighttype="+pweighttype+"&description=hello&image="+abcd;




                 // open a URL connection to the Servlet
               FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
               URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

               // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
               conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
               conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
               conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
               conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
               conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
               conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

               conn.setRequestProperty("name", pname);
               conn.setRequestProperty("categoryid", catsids);
               conn.setRequestProperty("skucode", pskucode);
               conn.setRequestProperty("sale_rate", psalerate);
               conn.setRequestProperty("purchase_rate", ppurchaserate);
               conn.setRequestProperty("weight", pweight);
               conn.setRequestProperty("weighttype", pweighttype);
               conn.setRequestProperty("description", "hello");
             //  conn.setRequestProperty("displayorder", pdisporder);
              // conn.setRequestProperty("active", pproactives);
               conn.setRequestProperty("image", abcd.toString()); 


               dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 

               dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"type\""
                         + lineEnd);
                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                 // assign value
                 /*dos.writeBytes("version=apps");
                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);*/

                 dos.writeBytes("name="+pname);
                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);


                 dos.writeBytes("categoryid="+catsids);
                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                 dos.writeBytes("skucode="+pskucode);
                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                 dos.writeBytes("sale_rate="+psalerate);
                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                 dos.writeBytes("purchase_rate="+ppurchaserate);
                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                 dos.writeBytes("weight="+pweight);
                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                 dos.writeBytes("weighttype="+pweighttype);
                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                 dos.writeBytes("description="+"hello");
                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);


                /* dos.writeBytes("displayorder="+pdisporder);
                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                 dos.writeBytes("active="+pproactives);
                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);*/



               dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\";filename=\""
                                         + abcd.toString() + "\"" + lineEnd);

               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

               // create a buffer of  maximum size
               bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

               bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
               buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

               // read file and write it into form...
               bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

               while (bytesRead > 0) {

                 dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                 bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                 bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                 bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                }

               // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

               // Responses from the server (code and message)
               serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
               String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

               Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                       + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

               if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                  +" F:/wamp/wamp/www/uploads";
                            messageText.setText(msg);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });                
               }
```

Fullcode

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

```
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
private TextView messageText;
private Button uploadButton;
private ImageView imageview;
private int serverResponseCode = 0;
private ProgressDialog dialog = null;

private String upLoadServerUri = null;
private String imagepath=null;

private EditText proname;
private EditText proskucode;

private EditText prodesc;
//private CheckBox proactives;
private ImageView btnselectpic;

private String pskucode;


private EditText prosalerate;
private EditText propurchaserate;
private EditText proweight;
private EditText proweighttype;
//private EditText prodisporder;
private String pname;
private String psalerate;
private String ppurchaserate;
private String pweight;
private String pweighttype;
private String pproactives;
private String pdisporder;
private String pdesc;
private List<String> catid=new ArrayList<String>();
private AutoCompleteTextView acTextView;
private String catsids;
private Uri selectedImageUri;
private int columnIndex;
private ImageAdapter objImageAdapter;
private GridView gridView;
private JSONArray abcd;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    //gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    objImageAdapter= new ImageAdapter(this); 
    gridView.setAdapter(objImageAdapter);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, 
        View v, int position, long id) 
        {                
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                    "pic" + (position + 1) + " selected", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });        

    acTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.multautoComplete);
    acTextView.setAdapter(new SuggestionAdapter(this,acTextView.getText().toString()));
  //  acTextView.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());

   proname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_proname);
    proskucode=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_proskucode);
    prosalerate=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_salerate);
    propurchaserate=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_purchaserate);
    proweight=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_weight);
    proweighttype=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_weighttype);
 //  prodesc=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_desc);
  // prodisporder=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_disporder);
  // proactives=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.edt_proactive);

   uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_addpro);
    messageText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edt_imgs);
    btnselectpic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.browsesimgs);
    imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagevw);


    btnselectpic.setOnClickListener(this);
    uploadButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    if(arg0==btnselectpic)
    {
        /*Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,PhotoSelection.class);
        startActivity(intent);*/

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        /*Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 1);*/

        /*Intent i = new Intent(Action.ACTION_MULTIPLE_PICK);
        startActivityForResult(i, 200);*/
    }
    else if (arg0==uploadButton) {

         dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
         messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
         new Thread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {            
                  uploadFile(imagepath);                       
             }
           }).start();     
    }

} 

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

     if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
         selectedImageUri= data.getData();
         String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

         Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImageUri,
                 filePathColumn, null, null, null);
         cursor.moveToFirst();

        /* columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
         picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
         cursor.close();*/

       //  imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
         imageview.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath));

         columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
         String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
         objImageAdapter.addToList(picturePath);
         cursor.close();
        // addmores.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }

    /*if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getData().getPath(); 

        selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        imagepath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
        Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
        imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        messageText.setText("Uploading file path:" +imagepath);

    }*/
}
     public String getPath(Uri uri) {
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }

     public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
     {
   private Context context;
   ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<String>();

   public ImageAdapter(Context c) 
   {
       context = c;
   }

   //---returns the number of images---
   public int getCount() {
       return arrayList.size();
   }

   //---returns the ID of an item--- 
   public Object getItem(int position) {
       return position;
   }

   void addToList(String strPath)
   {
       this.arrayList.add(strPath);
       this.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
   public long getItemId(int position) {
       return position;
   }

   //In this array you have to store all images path which is you want to display in baseapater and must be global to access in baseapater  

   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
   {
       ImageView imageView;
       if (convertView == null) {
           imageView = new ImageView(context);
           imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(185, 185));
           imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
           imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
       } else {
           imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
       }
       String path = arrayList.get(position);
       Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
       imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
       return imageView;
   }
    }    

public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


      String fileName = sourceFileUri;

      /*String[] mimgs = null;
      mimgs.equals(fileName);*/

      ArrayList<String> multimgss=new ArrayList<String>();
      multimgss.add(fileName);

      System.out.println("multipleimagesss"+multimgss);


    try {
        abcd = new JSONArray(multimgss.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
      //abcd=multimgss.add(fileName);


      HttpURLConnection conn = null;
      DataOutputStream dos = null;  
      String lineEnd = "\r\n";
      String twoHyphens = "--";
      String boundary = "*****";
      int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
      byte[] buffer;
      int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
      File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

      if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

           dialog.dismiss(); 

           Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"+imagepath);

           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"+ imagepath);
               }
           }); 

           return 0;

      }
      else
      {
           try { 


               String cats[]=acTextView.getText().toString().split(",");
               JsonParse jp=new JsonParse();
               for(String cat:cats){
                   List<SuggestGetSet> list =jp.getParseJsonWCF(acTextView.getText().toString());
                for(int i = 0;i<list.size();i++){
                  if(list.get(i).getName().equals(cat))
                      catid.add(list.get(i).getId().toString());
                   //params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("parentid",list.get(i).getId()));


                } 
               }
               catsids=catid.toString();
               pname = proname.getText().toString();
                pskucode = proskucode.getText().toString();
                psalerate=prosalerate.getText().toString();
                ppurchaserate=propurchaserate.getText().toString();
                pweight = proweight.getText().toString();
                pweighttype=proweighttype.getText().toString();
            //  pproactives = proactives.getTag().toString();

                 System.out.println("active nu stauts"+catsids);
            //  pdisporder = prodisporder.getText().toString();
                pdesc = prodesc.getText().toString();

                upLoadServerUri = "http://mywebsitename/web-service/addproduct.php?action=addproduct&name="+pname+"&categoryid="+catsids+"&skucode="+pskucode+"&sale_rate="+psalerate+"&purchase_rate="+ppurchaserate+"&weight="+pweight+"&weighttype="+pweighttype+"&description=hello&image="+abcd;




                 // open a URL connection to the Servlet
               FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
               URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

               // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
               conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
               conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
               conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
               conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
               conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
               conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

               conn.setRequestProperty("name", pname);
               conn.setRequestProperty("categoryid", catsids);
               conn.setRequestProperty("skucode", pskucode);
               conn.setRequestProperty("sale_rate", psalerate);
               conn.setRequestProperty("purchase_rate", ppurchaserate);
               conn.setRequestProperty("weight", pweight);
               conn.setRequestProperty("weighttype", pweighttype);
               conn.setRequestProperty("description", "hello");

               conn.setRequestProperty("image", abcd.toString()); 


               dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 

               dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"type\""
                         + lineEnd);
                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);


                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);*/

                 dos.writeBytes("name="+pname);
                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);


                 dos.writeBytes("categoryid="+catsids);
                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                 dos.writeBytes("skucode="+pskucode);
                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                 dos.writeBytes("sale_rate="+psalerate);
                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                 dos.writeBytes("purchase_rate="+ppurchaserate);
                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                 dos.writeBytes("weight="+pweight);
                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                 dos.writeBytes("weighttype="+pweighttype);
                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                 dos.writeBytes("description="+"hello");
                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);


               dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\";filename=\""
                                         + abcd.toString() + "\"" + lineEnd);

               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

               // create a buffer of  maximum size
               bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

               bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
               buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

               // read file and write it into form...
               bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

               while (bytesRead > 0) {

                 dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                 bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                 bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                 bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                }

               // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

               // Responses from the server (code and message)
               serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
               String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

               Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                       + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

               if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                  +" F:/wamp/wamp/www/uploads";
                            messageText.setText(msg);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });                
               }    


               fileInputStream.close();
               dos.flush();
               dos.close();

          } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

              dialog.dismiss();  
              ex.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });

              Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
          } catch (Exception e) {

              dialog.dismiss();  
              e.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });
              Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "  + e.getMessage(), e);  
          }
          dialog.dismiss();       
          return serverResponseCode; 

       } 
     }
```

}

[image]

Comment: Issue is occurring because `setRequestProperty` accept only String as second parameter. so instead of passing `multimgss` ArrayList create a JSONArray or JSONObject from `multimgss` then pass it to `setRequestProperty` . any issue in passing Images in  `JSONArray or JSONObject` ?

Comment: how to pass using jsonarray?

Comment: use `conn.setRequestProperty("image", jsonarray.toString()); ` for passing JSONArray

Comment: yes but how to multiimgss in jsonarray?.i am trying this way..JSONArray abcd=new JSONArray();
          abcd=multimgss.toString();..but not working

Comment: i also updated full code..when i run app it says..04-20 12:59:20.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1177): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-107
04-20 12:59:20.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1177): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-20 12:59:20.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):  at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:185)
04-20 12:59:20.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):  at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:134)

Answer (score 0):

You can send `String` parameter as both field with `setRequestProperty()`

Problem : In second parameter, you are passing `ArrayList<String>`

Try to pass  every element of `multimgss` one by one with `setRequestProperty()`

```
               FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
           URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

           // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
           conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
           conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
           conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
           conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
           conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
           conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
           conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
           conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

           conn.setRequestProperty("name", pname);
           conn.setRequestProperty("categoryid", catsids);
           conn.setRequestProperty("skucode", pskucode);
           conn.setRequestProperty("sale_rate", psalerate);
           conn.setRequestProperty("purchase_rate", ppurchaserate);
           conn.setRequestProperty("weight", pweight);
           conn.setRequestProperty("weighttype", pweighttype);
           conn.setRequestProperty("description", pdesc);


          conn.setRequestProperty("image", multimgss.get(i++));   
           // it will give i th element
```

Note : From Android Developer documentation for `setRequestProperty()`

> Sets the value of the specified request header field. The value will only be used by the current URLConnection instance. This method can only be called before the connection is established.

So, you need to call this method everytime before establishing connection

Comment: What is problem are you getting? You should pass String as second parameter in `setRequestProperty`.. R u doing same?

Comment: my full code is so much long otherwise i surely post here

Comment: see my updated code..i sysout multimgss and in my logcat it shows..multipleimagesss[null]

Answer (score 0):

`setRequestProperty` method only accept `String` instead of `ArrayList` . get `JSONArray` from `ArrayList` as:

```
JSONArray jsonArrayImgs=new JSONArray();
 ArrayList<String> multimgss=new ArrayList<String>();
 for (String string : multimgss)
  {
    jsonArrayImgs.put(string);
  }
```

Now pass `jsonArrayImgs` to `setRequestProperty` :

```
conn.setRequestProperty("image", jsonArrayImgs.toString());
```

**EDIT:**

`sourceFileUri`  is `null` . so update `getItem` method as of Adapter:

```
public String getItem(int position) {
       return arrayList.get[position];
   }
```

now inside `onItemClick` of `GridView`  asign selected image path to `sourceFileUri` as:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, 
        View v, int position, long id) 
        {                
             imagepath=objImageAdapter.getItem(position);
        }
```

Comment: app crash and it shows error see my edited question i posted logcat

Comment: @chris: what is line number `290` ?

Comment: still no change..same error and same line File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

Comment: @chris: what problem getting now?

Comment: same problem as mentioned in my question logcat image..can you tell when i sysout multimgss it shows null..

Comment: i also made changes as per your answer