# How to Share Image using Facebook android

Tags: android, facebook, baseadapter, facebook-share

I am trying to share Image and Content via Facebook,but what i am trying is if user is not logged in via Facebook,and user click on Share button then first it should ask for login,but when i run my code i am not getting error but nothing happen in screen and it goes in my else part and in logcat it display message of else part

Adapter

```
 holder.sharefb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (strtextfb == null) {


                        share();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Methods

```
 public void RequestData(){
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,GraphResponse response) {

                JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();
                try {
                    if(json != null){
                        String text = "<b>Name :</b> "+json.getString("name")+"<br><br><b>Email :</b> "+json.getString("email")+"<br><br><b>Profile link :</b> "+json.getString("link");
                       // details_txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
                       // profile.setProfileId(json.getString("id"));


                       // System.out.println("FbId" + fbids);

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,email,picture");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    }

    public void share() {
         if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
        RequestData();
        String pictureUrl = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/90/Bale_as_Batman.jpg";
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("name", "" + "Aditya");
        params.putString("message", "" + "Nver Give Up");
        params.putString("caption", "" + "Hi");
        params.putString("description", "" + "Lie Cheat Steal");
        params.putString("link", "" + "https://www.google.co.in/");
        if (pictureUrl != "")
            params.putString("picture", "" + pictureUrl);
    /* make the API call */
        new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "/me/feed",
                params,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    /* handle the result */
                        Log.e("res", "" + response.getError());
                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse graphResponse) {

                            }
                        });

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException e) {

                    }
                });
                System.out.println("else part");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call below code on click of button from adapter.

```html
List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");

  manager = LoginManager.getInstance();

  manager.logInWithPublishPermissions(this, permissionNeeds);

  manager.registerCallback(callbackManager,
    new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
      publishImage();

     }

     @Override
     public void onCancel() {
      System.out.println("onCancel");
     }

     @Override
     public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
      System.out.println("onError");
     }
    });

 }


    private void publishImage() {
  Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
    R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    //You need to get bitmap from any source.

  SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(image)
    .setCaption("Welcome To Facebook Photo Sharing on steroids!")
    .build();

  SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder().addPhoto(
    photo).build();

  ShareApi.share(content, null);
  Toast.makeText(this, "Succsesfully posted on your wall",
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 }
```

Comment: @Arth Tilva Can u please help me with this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34198028/is-it-possible-to-share-multiple-photos-and-texts-to-facebook-from-my-android-ap

Answer (score 1):

First time when you try to log in, access token is null. So, it is going on else part. Do this in else part, I think so it may work for you :

```
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mcallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()
            {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse graphResponse) {

}
});

}
});
```

Comment: Unexpected CallbackManager, please use the provided Factory. it gives this error

Comment: ok i add this in my oncreate callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();..and error has gone..but still it show else part message only

Comment: Read my answer first line, to put this code in else part

Comment: it is in else part only

Answer (score 0):

```
first add 
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();    
permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
        manager = LoginManager.getInstance();   
**on onCreate and wirte below code in send button lick event**
 send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        if (isOnline()) {
                            new WebView(MainActivity.this);

                            manager.logInWithPublishPermissions(MainActivity.this, permissionNeeds);
                            manager.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                                    sharePhotoToFacebook();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancel() {
                                    System.out.println("onCancel");
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {

                                    exception.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            });


                            alertDialog.dismiss();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please check internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                });


     private void sharePhotoToFacebook() {
            try {
                Log.i("Facebook Image", camera_pathname + "");
                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(camera_pathname);
                //Bitmap image = decodeFile(camera_pathname);
                image = getResizedBitmap(image);
                //Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

                SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                        .setBitmap(image)
                        .setCaption(et_hashtag.getText().toString())
                        .build();

                SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                        .addPhoto(photo)
                        .build();

                ShareApi.share(content, null);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Shared successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // manager.logOut();
        }
```

Comment: what is send..i have only one listener to share

Comment: and my button is in adapter,,i have listview bhai