# Is it possible to share multiple photos and texts to Facebook from my Android app?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to integrate Facebook sharing in my Android app. I have multiple images and 4 texts to share. So my question is:

1. Can i use Intent for this purpose other than using Facebook SDK?
2. I have added Facebook library and done a sample for login and simple sharing like mentioned in [Sharing on Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android).Can i use this for my requirement?

Code:

```
ShareButton shareButton = (ShareButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_share_button);

    ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("og:type", "books.book")
            .putString("og:title", "A Game of Thrones")
            .putString(
                    "og:description",
                    "In the frozen wastes to the north of Winterfell, sinister and supernatural forces are mustering.")
            .putString("books:isbn", "0-553-57340-3").build();

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap)
            .setUserGenerated(true).build();

    // Create an action
    ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType("books.reads").putObject("book", object)
            .putPhoto("image", photo).build();

    // Create the content
    ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setPreviewPropertyName("book").setAction(action).build();
    ShareDialog.show(MainActivity.this, content);
    shareButton.setShareContent(content);
```

Comment: Have you completed sharing with single image?

Answer (score 0):

For multiple photos you need to add put photos multiple time. Suppose you have 3 images to share. You need to implement following code.

```html
ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType("books.reads").putObject("book", object)
            .putPhoto("image", photo)
            .putPhoto("image", photo)
            .putPhoto("image", photo).build();
```

You can make this code dynamic according to your need. It works fine for me to share multiple images.

Also there is one method addPhotos in **SharePhotoContent**, I have used below code for sharing images. I am able to give **List<>** in **addPhotos** method.

```html
private void publishImage() {
  Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
    R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    //You need to get bitmap from any source.

  SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(image)
    .setCaption("Welcome To Facebook Photo Sharing on steroids!")
    .build();

  SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder().addPhoto(
    photo).build();

  ShareApi.share(content, null);
  Toast.makeText(this, "Succsesfully posted on your wall",
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 }
```

Comment: What if the data is dynamic? I don't know the number of images i would've to share